# reverse magsafe adapter? (magsafe2 power to magsafe1 laptop)

Tags: power, magsafe

I have some magsafe2 power cords. That's fine, but occasionally I need to loan power to an older laptop that has the magsafe1 port.

I carry a magsafe2 adapter so I can steal power from them. But is there a "reverse adapter" so the magsafe2 cord can power a magsafe1 laptop?

Comment: Given the small size of the taller and narrower MagSafe 1 to shorter and wider MagSafe 2 adapter and that it's just made of metal and magnets and passes DC current, it's only a matter of time until someone makes a product to serve this market. Hopefully it will be a high quality part with good tolerances and proper alignment.

Comment: agree @bmike! it isn't insurmountable, I'm surprised someone hasn't done it.